Can not update from field in CiviMail
A colleague is facing an unusual issue. The 'from' field in their email in CiviMail is hidden, displaying only a line instead of the actual field (see pic). As a result, they are unable to update the 'from' field when composing this email. I've tried copying the email but the same thing happens. All other emails in draft are fine! Any help in trying to fix this would be greatly appreciated.


Yes, it is a known issue with the bootstrap theme reported at https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/628
We were able to fix it by adding the following CSS into our theme css or custom civicrm css
.form-group .select2-container.ng-not-empty a {
  min-height:30px;
}


Thanks Pradeep thats great. Much appreciated.
